# IOS TAb bar cannot hide on subView

Tags: ios, objective-c, tabbar

I'm learning IOS now, and working on Tab Bar Veiw Controller. I want to hide the tab bar on sub view, so I set 'Hides Bottom Bar On Push' true, it's working fine on second view. But if I set it true on Third View, the Tab Bar is not hidden.

How can I hide the tab bar when third view push?

I already try to find the result on line, but cannot find, please help me.

Comment: Put your code here for push on third view controller. and viewdidload of your third view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow code below, hope can help you

```
DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
detailViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
[detailViewController release];
```

Comment: I already try this, when push second this function is work. but if set it on second view to push third view it is not work